# Extracting Info From A Column that contains irregular structure of ";" and "|" separators

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame in which one of the columns looks like this.

```
INFO
SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233
SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233;CSQT=1|BHAT12|ESNT12345|
SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233;CSQT=1|JHV87|ESNT12345|,1|HJJUB2|ESNT12345|
SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233;CSQT=1|GFTREF|ESNT12345|,1|321lkj|ESNT12345|,1|16-YHGT|ESNT12345|...
```

The information I want to extract in new columns is `gene|ESNT12345` . For the same example should be

```
gene1               gene2               gene3
Na                  Na                  Na
BHAT12|ESNT12345 Na                  Na
JHV87|ESNT12345 HJJUB2|ESNT12345 Na
GFTREF|ESNT12345 321lkj|ESNT12345 16-YHGT|ESNT12345
```

How can I do this working with pandas? I have been trying with `.apply(lambda x:x.split("|")`. But as I don't know the number of `gene_name|ESNT12345` my dataset has and also this will be used in an application that will take thousands of different data frames, I am looking for a way of dynamically creating the necessary columns.

How can I do this?

Comment: is `gene_name` a literal string?

Comment: what do you mean with a literal string? The entire column info is treated as str

Comment: I meant is this the word `gene_name` or you called it gene name but it could be `abc123`

Comment: some gene names has number on it such as NBPF17P

Comment: can you try [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71125953/16343464) and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: For sure. I am going to have a look at. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No working. It is a long error message. I have paste the error here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q1UpIy9H0RNdmgqBuLtQ1dp0AXmPs68l1BdXtvLTQwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yes this is why I asked you if `gene_name` was literal. So, it is not ;) Please update the data in the question with real gene names. Also, are the strings after the gene names always starting with "ESNT"?

Comment: Try changing the regex to `r'(\w+\|ESNT\d+)'` (or ENST, not sure which one is correct)

Comment: I have updated the questions and I have tried your new suggestion. This time I don't get any error but neither any new column

Comment: which code have you tested? None add a new column, the first returns a new dataframe combined to the original data, the other two make new dataframes. You need to assign the output to some variable ;) I updated my code to show you how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a regex and [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html).

##### joining to the original data:

```
new_df = df.join(
 df['INFO']
 .str.extractall(r'(\w+\|ESNT\d+)')[0]
 .unstack(level='match')
 .add_prefix('gene_')
)
```

output:

```
                                                                                         INFO            gene_0            gene_1          gene_2
0                                                                       SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233               NaN               NaN             NaN
1                                              SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233;CSQT=1|BHAT12|ESNT12345|  BHAT12|ESNT12345               NaN             NaN
2                           SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233;CSQT=1|JHV87|ESNT12345|,1|HJJUB2|ESNT12345|   JHV87|ESNT12345  HJJUB2|ESNT12345             NaN
3  SVTYPE=CNV;END=401233;CSQT=1|GFTREF|ESNT12345|,1|321lkj|ESNT12345|,1|16-YHGT|ESNT12345|...  GFTREF|ESNT12345  321lkj|ESNT12345  YHGT|ESNT12345
```

##### without joining to the original data:

```
new_df = (df['INFO']
 .str.extractall(r'(\w+\|ESNT\d+)')[0]
 .unstack(level='match')
 .add_prefix('gene_')
 .reindex(df.index)
)
```

output:

```
match            gene_0            gene_1          gene_2
0                   NaN               NaN             NaN
1      BHAT12|ESNT12345               NaN             NaN
2       JHV87|ESNT12345  HJJUB2|ESNT12345             NaN
3      GFTREF|ESNT12345  321lkj|ESNT12345  YHGT|ESNT12345
```

###### regex hack to have gene1, gene2…

If you really want to have the genes counter to start with 1, you could use this small regex hack (match the beginning of the string as match `0` and drop it):

```
new_df = (df['INFO']
 .str.extractall(r'(^|\w+\|ESNT\d+)')[0]
 .unstack(level='match')
 .iloc[:, 1:]
 .add_prefix('gene')
 .reindex(df.index)
)
```

output:

```
match             gene1             gene2           gene3
0                   NaN               NaN             NaN
1      BHAT12|ESNT12345               NaN             NaN
2       JHV87|ESNT12345  HJJUB2|ESNT12345             NaN
3      GFTREF|ESNT12345  321lkj|ESNT12345  YHGT|ESNT12345
```

Comment: Genius! That almost worked. I have found that some genes present "-" and "." I show you what happens with genes like that. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q1UpIy9H0RNdmgqBuLtQ1dp0AXmPs68l1BdXtvLTQwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Manuel, then just update the regex. Use `[\w.-]` in place of `\w` or even `[\|]`

Comment: Worked at least with these three examples.  I need to understand how this str.extractall works because is very handy. Many thanks!